# How can I align the center of a float and its caption to the center of the previous paragraph?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I don't know if I explained myself properly with the title, but I want to be able to center a float and its caption the same way a equation is centered when used in a `enumerate` (or similar) environment.

What I have right now is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{mypreamble}

\title{My Style for \LaTeX\ Documents}
\author{Andrés Moreno}
\date{28 de marzo de 2022}

\doublespacing
\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle

    \section*{Blah, blah, blah...}
        Blah, blah, blah...

    \section*{Blah, blah, blah...}
        Blah, blah, blah...

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Blah, blah, blah...
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2 + 3}{x - 1}$
                    
                        El dominio de una función se define como el conjunto de todos los $x$ que generen una imagen $y$. Además, dividir entre $0$ no está definido. Por lo tanto, el dominio de $f$ será el conjunto de los $x$ que al meterlos en $f$ esté definido. Lo anterior es lo mismo que decir que $x - 1$ no puede ser $0$, por lo que $x - 1 = 0 \rightarrow x = 1$ es el número que no pertenece al dominio de $f$.
                        \begin{equation*}
                            \text{Dom}(f): \{x\ |\ x \in (-\infty, 1) \cup (1, \infty)\}
                        \end{equation*}
                        \begin{table}[H]
                            \centering
                            \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
                                \hline
                                $x$ & $f(x)$ \\
                                \hline
                                $-1.5$ & $-2.1 $ \\
                                \hline
                                $-0.5$ & $-2.1\overline{6}$ \\
                                \hline
                                $0.5$ & $-6.5$ \\
                                \hline
                                $1.5$ & $10.5$ \\
                                \hline
                                $2.5$ & $6.1\overline{6}$ \\
                                \hline
                                $3.5$ & $6.1$ \\
                                \hline
                            \end{tabular}
                            \caption{Esta tabla}
                        \end{table}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which compiles to:

[image: My result]

If I'm not wrong, the table leaves the same amount of space before and after. But as can be seen, the table is not centered the same way the equation is.

How can I make it happen?

BTW, mypreamble.sty is:

```
% !TeX root = main.tex

% For project modularity. For example \import{tex/}{test}, and this would import a test.tex file.
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

% To modify the dimentions of the document.
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

% To change the main font used in the document.
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

% To change the math font used in the document.
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

% To change the language of the document.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Typographic and hyphenation goodness
\usepackage[babel=true, final]{microtype}

% Bibliography management.
\usepackage{biblatex}

% For testing the whole thing before.
% \usepackage{blindtext}

% For easy quotes
\usepackage{csquotes}

%%% Math related goodness

% The best thing in history
\usepackage{amsmath}

% For improving the derivative package.
\usepackage{mleftright}

% For writing partial and ordinary derivatives in a straight forward manner.
% \odv{} (ordinary), \pdv{} (partial), \mdv{} (material, with the D), \fdv{} (functional, with the delta and not Delta), \adv{} (average rate of change, with Delta), \jdv{} (jacobian).
\usepackage{derivative}

% To be able to use singlespace in equations. This fixes some things in math mode. {\siglespacing ...} or with \begin{singlespace}
\usepackage{setspace}

%%% Other components of the document

% Support for images.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{images/}

% Support for exact placement of figures [H]
\usepackage{float}

% Support for multiple columns.
\usepackage{multicol}

% To be able to define the position of a caption.
% To be able to use captions outside of a float you need: \captionsetup{type=<type of float>}. For example \captionsetup{type=table or figure, etc...}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, center]{caption}


%%%% Custom functions
```

Comment: don't use a float, the whole point about a float is that it is not in the main document flow so not "in" the list, it is centred on `\extwidth` not on the item width. To have a table in the list item just use `\begin{center}`  (you could use `\captionof` if you want to caption it)

Comment: Yes, I though of that. The table is centered properly but the caption is not. The caption stays in the same horizontal position. That is why I asked for both the table and the caption.

Comment: I wouldn't caption a non floating table but you should be able to use a `\begin{minipage}{\linewidh}\centering` ... to get image and caption centred in a minipage tha fits the list `\linwiidth`